# Which level should I mock the dependency when the dependency is complicated?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

Now I hava a class A to be tested. When I test a method(called Amethod) of A, Amethod will invoke another method(called Bmethod) of class B. And in this method of B, Bmethod will invoke a method of a interface C.
It just likes a dependency tree:

```
A->B->C
```

I am using the gmock to do the unit test of Amethod of class A. Which one I should mock, B or C?

Comment: Read about law of demeter - good programming practices like LoD are just to prevent from cases like this one - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 0):

You should mock just the SUT's (System Under Test - `A` in your case) dependencies (`B` in your case), as in set up Bmethod to return a preset value, for example. You'd only worry about mocking `C` when testing `B`, and so on.

Comment: I know what you means. But mocking C is much more easier than mocking B by using gmock.  Because the class B is a concrete class, and the Bmethod is a non-virtual method. The C is a interface which has the virtual method.

Comment: have you given thought to abstracting away B's contract into an interface for the sake of testability?